# IO file attributes

Tags: java, file, attributes

```
import java.io.File;
class AttriDemo{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        File f1 = new File("FileIO/file.txt");
        System.out.println("File name           : " + f1.getName());
        System.out.println("File path           : " + f1.getPath());
        System.out.println("File AbsPath        : " + f1.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("File parent         : " + f1.getParent());
        f1.setWritable(true);
        if(f1.canWrite())
        {
            System.out.println("File is Writeable");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("File is not Writeable");
        }
        if(f1.canRead())
        {
            System.out.println("Is readable");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("File is not readable");
        }
    }
}
```

I the file is readable and writable in real...

then I tried setting it to Writable explicitly but still the output shows it as the file is not writable!!

output:

```
....
The file is not writable.
The file is not readable.
```

---

```
File f1 = new File("D:/javaProgs/FileIO/AttriDemo.java");
```

doing this helps solve the problem. 
but can someone explain how? I mean the file was in the same directory and the statements above were running just fine. e.g getName() getParent()

Comment: have you tried the code with the other files?

Comment: Well, you're output shows it's not readable either. So, I guess it does not exist, at least not where you think it does.

Comment: One possible reason is that the file does not exist. Are you sure the path is correct? Have you tried to specify the full path in your `File` constructor?

Comment: yes I have tried with other files too

Comment: file is in the same directory as the code. is that enough or setting more path is needed?

Comment: What is important is what the working directory is, when executing the   code. It expects a subdirectory (in that working directory) called FileIO with a file called file.txt.

Comment: As an aside, having just accused someone of providing an answer that does not answer the question, prompts me to ask.  What ***is*** the question?

Comment: @AndrewThompson the question is: f1 is the handler and is working fine. (we know that because the getName(), getPath(), getAbsolutePate() are working just fine.

why doesn't the canWrite() and canRead() give the correct output.

Comment: check exists on that handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's fooling you is you can create a File object regardless of the path you specified exists or not and you can call all those `getParent`, `getPath` functions on that object.

You can create a File object that's not backed by a real file for various reasons like to check if it exists or to create a file specified by that objects path and name.

You can use [File.exists()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) to see if file really exists on file system.